# How to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l\geq k}a_ka_l e^{2k}\leq C \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{2k}a_k^2$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, summation

Let $a=\{a_k\}_{k\geq 0}$ be a sequence of real number satisfying that $\|a\|_1=h>1$, and $\|a\|_2\leq 1$, where the 1-norm and 2-norm are defined by:
$$
\|a\|_p^p=\sum_{k=0}^\infty|a_k|^p,\quad p\geq 1.
$$
Here is my question. I want to prove that there exists a universal constant $C>0$ which is independent of $h$ and the sequence $a=\{a_k\}$, such that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l\geq k}a_ka_l e^{2k}\leq C \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{2k}a_k^2.
$$
Here is my attempt:

Firstly, I prefer to exchange the order of the summation, that is,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l\geq k}a_ka_l e^{2k}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^la_ka_l e^{2k}.
$$
Then, use the Young inequality, we have
$$
\sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^la_ka_l e^{2k}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^l (\epsilon a_k^2e^{2k}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}a_l^2e^{2k}).
$$
where $\epsilon=\epsilon(l)$ is a small constant depending on $l$.
In my attempt, for each $l$, I try to bound the first term in the RHS by $\epsilon\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{2k}a_k^2$, then select $\epsilon(l)$ to satisfy $\sum_{l=0}^\infty \epsilon(l)<\infty$. As for the second term of the RHS, we know
$$
\sum_{k=0}^l a_l^2e^{2k}=a_l^2\frac{e^{2l+2}-1}{e^2-1}.
$$
Thus, to make sure $\sum_{k=0}^l a_l^2e^{2k}\leq C_1 a_l^2e^{2l}$ for some constant $C_1>0$, the only possibility of selection of $\epsilon(l)$ is a constant. But if $\epsilon$ is a constant independent of $l$, then the first term will blow up, and I don't know how to handle this problem.

Please provide my some help. Any help will be appreciated a lot!